Trying to find out the head of degree, result and concession phrases


He is taller than I am.
They didn't play so well as we expected.
He is so weak that he can not carry the load.
Though he is poor, he is large-hearted.


From these sentences, I can't find out the modified words.
I know that bold clauses are adverbials. But then I am confused.
In the main clauses, are all main verbs being modified by these adverbial modifier or something else?
Please, explain these sentences!

Modified words? What do you mean by that? All sorts of words can be modified in all sorts of ways.

@PeterKirkpatrick it means modified part of speech (like verbs) that is modified by an adverbial modifier...

I wonder if you are making this too complex. Consider the sentence, The boy ran fast. Are you calling the word fast an adverbial modifier? It's modifying the verb ran. But I would simply call it an adverb. So why are you talking about modifiers? Are you following a text book?

@PeterKirkpatrick He is taller than I am. Is than I am giving extra information about taller or the verb is?

You haven't answered my question. Why is the word modifier important to you? As for your sentence, I wouldn't analyse that way at all. Consider this variation: He is tall: taller than I am. Here the additional clause is adding to the whole sentence, not any particular word.

@PeterKirkpatrick Because I want to know the syntax properly.

But, @Salimuddin, what makes you confident that modification is what than I am is doing in a sentence like He is taller than I am? One thing it is certainly doing is completing the comparative taller than I am, and that comparative is performing modification: it modifies he.

Your sentence #2 should be "didn't play as well as we expected" if you expected them to play better than they did and "... didn't play so well, as we expected" if you expected them to play poorly and they did.

@Salimuddin, understanding syntax is a good goal. But you don't need to discuss modifiers to do that. He is the subject; is is the verb; taller than I am is the complement. That's where I would start. Personally I've spent the last two hours googling articles about "adverbial modifiers". So I know accept that it's a thing, but I found nothing that made analysis of syntax any easier. If you are in a formal course that requires this way of thinking, then the teacher should answer your questions. Otherwise....

The four examples have rather different syntax.  The first is just normal comparative construction.  The second is a rather misformed comparative. The third and fourth have different syntax.  There is no overarching theme to understand the syntax. I think there are four questions here, not one.  So this question would benefit from being cut down to a single example and a lot more detail about your difficulties.  Try including a parse tree in your question.

@PeterKirkpatrick He's just trying to indentify which words the adverbs apply to. E.g. in "He is running quickly", the adverb modifies "running".

I am trying to indentify the head in comparative phrase. So, He is taller than I am. Here in the comparative phrase taller than I am. Maybe the head is taller.

@Barmar, yes, but he's doing it in a very confused way. If you look at his first example, there is no adverb, so talking about adverbial modifiers misses the whole point.

@Salimuddin, I'm realising that this is more a question about technical lignuistics than I realised. That's not my area of expertise. But if that's your interest, I would urge you to work on the basics first. For example, in the OP you described the bolded clauses as adverbials. Personally I would challenge that description in those sentences. If we continued the conversation I would ask you to be precise as to which words/phrases are adverbial, and why. Be sure you are clear on the basics first.

@PeterKirkpatrick "than I am" is an adverbial prepositional phrase that qualifies "taller".

OP has enquired about what the adverbial clause is modifying in the four sentences:.
Adverbial clauses, like adverbs, modify a verb, an adjective, another adverb, or an entire clause.

1. He is taller than I am..
than I am: Adverbial clause of comparison modifying the adjective  "taller.".
.
2. They didn't play so well as we expected..
as we expected: Adverbial clause of degree modifying the adverbial phrase "so well.".
.
3. He is so weak that he cannot carry the load..
that he cannot carry the load: Adverbial clause of result modifying the adjective phrase  "so weak.".
.
4. Though he is poor, he is large-hearted..
though he is poor: Adverbial clause of concession modifying the main clause  "he is large-hearted."

Additional Note:

Adverbial clauses are versatile and express various relationships, such as location, time, reason, condition, degree/comparison, concession, and manner, among others. Here is a useful chart and the link below to help you understand the different types of adverbial clauses:
.


Source: Adverbial clauses

I respect that you are trying to help. But this is the whole problem I have. I would analyse your sentences differently. (1) How can an adverbial clause qualify one of the words inside the clause? Surely it qualifies the verb to be. (2) I would say the adverbial phrase is so well as we expected, and it qualifies the verb play. And so on. Having read some refresher articles in the last 24 hours I accept I may be out on a limb here, but for non-native English speakers I wonder how helpful all this analysis is.

@PeterKirkpatrick. Adverbial clauses never modify the be verb. In sentence 1, the clause than I am modifies taller by answering how much taller.
In sentence 2, the clause as we expected modifies so well by explaining how well. This analysis clarifies the function of adverbial clauses in sentence construction.

I think you're missing my point. I understand your analysis. I'm saying that we can take the same sentence and analyse it in different ways, all arguably valid. So in sentence #2, suppose we have They didn't play well. In that simplified sentence, well is an adverb, describing how they played. Right? So in the expanded sentence, why is it not so well as we expected that makes up the adverbial clause? I get your argument, but my argument seems equally valid, and it feels totally arbitrary where we draw the line.
